# Google Cloud Endpoints Developer Portal Remove get an API Key

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I want to remove the "**GET A KEY**" button from Google Cloud Endpoints Developer portal.
We don't want to offer this option to our developer since we handle the authentication in a different way.

In the examples provided by Google in two of them the button isn't shown.

Shown:
[image]
See [example](https://endpointsportal.endpoints-portal-demo.cloud.goog/docs/echo-api.endpoints.endpoints-portal-demo.cloud.goog/1/introduction)

Not shown:
[image]
See [example](https://endpointsportal.endpoints-portal-demo.cloud.goog/docs/bookstore.endpoints.endpoints-portal-demo.cloud.goog/g/introduction)

Does anyone know how to remove this, I can't find it in the portal settings nor in the documentation

Answer (score 1):

The first link you are referring to is an Endpoints Example page which is why it has the "Get a Key" button, and the second page is related to a specific API and doesn't have this button.

However, if you open the page under the "Getting started" button, there is still the same link to the Cloud Console where API keys are generated,
[image]
so I don't think it's possible to delete this reference from the portal.

You can [control who can enable your API](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/control-api-callers) by granting or removing respective IAM permissions.

Comment: That's a bummer since I don't want that to be shown to our API users, might be confusing since we don't allow API keys

Comment: @Jobias I think you can create a [Feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187193&template=0) about this for Google to consider